# evaluating scripts inline with node on windows

Tags: node.js, windows

When invoking node this way on Linux I get:

```
node -e 'console.log("hi")'
# prints 'hi'
```

Doing the same thing on Windows however yields nothing.
For completeness here are the versions I am using

- Windows: node v6.9.1
- Linux: node v4.4.7

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes:

```
 node -e "console.log('hi')"
```